# windows7 cygwin perl XML::Parser libexpat* : failing to install

Tags: xml, perl, cygwin

My immediate problem : trying to install the pel module XML:Parser using cpanm fails, apparently due to a dependency on expat-devel or libexpat1-dev, or similar.
( I need this XML::Parser module as a dependency of the end-goal Spreadsheet::ParseXLSX module. )

```
$ cpanm XML::Parser
--> Working on XML::Parser
Fetching http://www.cpan.org/authors/id/T/TO/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.46.tar.gz ... OK
Configuring XML-Parser-2.46 ... ! Configure failed for XML-Parser-2.46. See ~/.cpanm/work/1626990186.1404/build.log for details.
N/A
```

The relevent section of the build.log file seems to be

```
Expat must be installed prior to building XML::Parser and I can't find
it in the standard library directories. Install 'expat-devel' (or
'libexpat1-dev') package with your OS package manager. See 'README'.
```

Running the cygwin setup-x86_64.exe ( either version 2.908 or 2.909 ) I have installed "libexpat-devel" and "libexpat1" ... there is no listing of packages exactly named 'expat-devel' or 'libexpat1-dev'.

```
$ cygcheck -c libexpat-devel libexpat1
Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
libexpat-devel       2.2.6-1        OK
libexpat1            2.2.6-1        OK
```

I've done several iterations now; I believe the failure is reported exactly the same way whether neither, either one or both of these packages is installed.

I have a working cygwin+perl system on a second W7 laptop with these two "libexpat-devel" and "libexpat1" packages installed ( cygcheck output is identical ).  On that second laptop, the XML::Parser module installed successfully, and perl scripts which depend upon XML:Parser and Spreadsheet:ParseXLSX do run successfully.

I have not been able to figure out what is the difference between the two.  AFAICT the files which might ( should ? ) be relevent appear in the same cygwin filesystem locations on both laptops :

```
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/lib/libexpat.a
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/lib/libexpat.dll.a
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/lib/pkgconfig/expat.pc
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/expat.h
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/expat_config.h
/cygdrive/c/cygwin64/usr/include/expat_external.h
```

I have looked at several other questions which have related titles : the majority of the threads I found are (a) some years old and (b) discuss installing packages on a real Linux system using apt-get or equivalent.
Maybe my search-fu is not up to scratch, but I haven't found any recent questions relating to the exact naming variations of the "(lib)expat(1)-dev(el)" packages available to install using the cygwin setup-x86_64.exe, although I'm not confident whether that is the root of the problem or merely a distraction.

Thanks in advance for any enlightenment and/or suggestions of how to proceed.

Comment: Try to install `expat` from category `Libs`, to see if it improves.

Comment: I tried to install `XML::Parser` on Cygwin on Windows 10 using the Cygwin perl (version 5.32.0). The first thing I noticed was that it was not enought to just install `libexpat-dev`, you also need `libnsl-dev`. I am not sure why yet. After this I could generate a `Makefile` (running `perl Makefile.PL` from the source directory).

Comment: ... However, running `make` failed with `g++  --shared  -Wl,--enable-auto-import -Wl,--export-all-symbols -Wl,--enable-auto-image-base -fstack-protector-strong  Parser.o  -o blib/arch/auto/XML/Parser/Parser.dll   /usr/lib/perl5/5.32/x86_64-cygwin-threads/CORE/cygperl5_32.dll`. Here it tries to generate a `Parser.dll` file but `Parser.pm` is not an XS module, so this looks like a bug in `ExtUtils::MakeMaker`. I will have to look more into this tomorrow.

Comment: I'll try to look into this tomorrow.

Comment: @Philippe Btw. you could also try install [Strawberry Perl](https://strawberryperl.com/) it comes with `XML::Parser` preinstalled

Comment: *"... running make failed ..."* Strange, I tried again after erasing the source directory (`rm -rf XML-Parser-2.46; tar zxvf  XML-Parser-2.46.tar.gz; cd XML-Parser-2.46`) and now it installed fine.

Comment: @Philippe ... for completeness : to start with I did have "expat" explicitly installed via cygwin setup-x86_64.exe in addition to the "libexpat*" libraries ... that didn't make any difference.  Also, I uninstalled "expat" again at some point before getting "libnsl"installed (as per Håkon Hægland's answer/solution below); removing "expat" again has not prevented that solution from succeeding.

Comment: Can you get a better error message than "make failed". The error that caused make to fail would be helpful. The build.log may have those details.

Comment: There is a new version of expat on cygwin. Please upgrade to it, as it has some security patches and minor changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try install `libnsl-dev`. It seems like `XML::Parser` uses `Devel::CheckLib` to to check if the headers and libraries for Expat is present. It does this by creating a small C program containing an `#include <expat.h>` statement which it tries to compile with the C compiler and adding the linker flag `-lexpat`. The issue is that it also adds the linker flags from the `perl` config hash, which includes `-lnsl`.

```
$ perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{libs}'
-lpthread -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lcrypt -lgdbm_compat
```

Comment: OK, so I installed two "nsl" libraries using cygwin setup-x86_64.exe and cygcheck shows them as   
```
libnsl-devel             1.2.0-1            OK
libnsl2                  1.2.0-1            OK
```  
With these installed, ```cpanm XML::Parser``` does now succeed.

Thanks for this insight.  Can I ask how you get to see the ```perl -Mconfig``` line above to figure this out ?

Comment: Also, for my education : can anyone tell me
1.  is there any significance in the difference between "libnsl-dev" and "libnsl_devel" ?
2. do I actually need both "libnsl-devel" and "libnsl2" installed ? or only one, and if so, which ?
3.  would the answers to (1) and (2) generalise to libexpat* ? ( and also to libcrypt* and other similar cases ? ) 
Thanks again.

Comment: "*can anyone tell me do I actually need both libnsl-devel and libnsl2 installed"* I think `libnsl-devel` includes `libnsl2`, so it should only be necessary to install `libnsl-devel`.

Comment: *"how you get to see the perl -Mconfig line above to figure this out ?"* I looked at the source, see [line 373](https://metacpan.org/release/TODDR/XML-Parser-2.46/source/inc/Devel/CheckLib.pm#L373). It adds `$Config{perllibs}` to the linker flags.

Comment: Tip: `perl -MConfig -E'say $Config{libs}'` can be written as `perl -V:libs`